# How Do I Delete Rows From TableLayout?

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm a noob to android development and I am having trouble deleting rows from a TableLayout that that is instantiated with one row inside a viewpager.  When user click a button 12 more rows are added.  Then when users click the button again those 12 rows should be deleted and another set of rows should be added.  However, whenever I try to delete the rows from the TableLayout, only the odd number rows are deleted instead of all the rows.  Any help resolving this is greatly appreciated.

ViewPager (where tablelayout instantiated)

```
 case 2:
                resId = R.layout.suggestedremedy_layout;    
                view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                remedyDescription = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.remedy_description);
                remedyCause = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.remedy_cause);
                remedyHerbs = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.remedy_herbs);
                remedyFoods = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.remedy_foods);
                remedyTable = (TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.remedy_table);

                TableRow titleRow = new TableRow(RemedyActivity.this);
                TextView titleSupplement = new TextView(RemedyActivity.this); 
                TextView titleDosage = new TextView(RemedyActivity.this);
                TextView titleComment = new TextView(RemedyActivity.this);
                titleSupplement.setText("Supplement");
                titleDosage.setText("Dosage");
                titleComment.setText("Comment");
                titleSupplement.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                titleDosage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                titleComment.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                titleRow.addView(titleSupplement);
                titleRow.addView(titleDosage);
                titleRow.addView(titleComment);
                remedyTable.addView(titleRow);                          

                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
                return view;
```

Button Click (where rows after title row are deleted and new rows added)

```
        //Updating Table  
        if(remedyTable.getChildCount()>0){
            for (int i = 0; i < remedyTable.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if(i>0){
                    remedyTable.removeViewAt(i); //Only removing odd rows, instead off all rows.  Why?
                }
            }
        }

        remedyItemsSupplements = new ArrayList<String>();
        remedyItemsDosage = new ArrayList<String>();
        remedyItemsComments = new ArrayList<String>();

        remedyDescription.setText(R.string.acne_description);
        remedyCause.setText(R.string.acne_cause);
        remedyHerbs.setText(R.string.acne_herbs);
        remedyFoods.setText(R.string.acne_foods);

        remedyListSupplements = res.getStringArray(R.array.acne_supplements);
        remedyListDosage = res.getStringArray(R.array.acne_dosage);
        remedyListComments = res.getStringArray(R.array.acne_comment);
        Collections.addAll(remedyItemsSupplements, remedyListSupplements);
        Collections.addAll(remedyItemsDosage, remedyListDosage);
        Collections.addAll(remedyItemsComments, remedyListComments);                      

        for (int i = 0; i < remedyItemsSupplements.size(); i++) {
            TableRow remedyRow = new TableRow(RemedyActivity.this);
            TextView remedySupplement = new TextView(RemedyActivity.this); 
            TextView remedyDosage = new TextView(RemedyActivity.this);
            TextView remedyComment = new TextView(RemedyActivity.this);

            remedySupplement.setText(remedyItemsSupplements.get(i));
            remedyDosage.setText(remedyItemsDosage.get(i));
            remedyComment.setText(remedyItemsComments.get(i));
            remedySupplement.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_background);
            remedyDosage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_background);
            remedyComment.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_background);
            remedySupplement.setHeight(80);
            remedySupplement.setWidth(500);
            remedyDosage.setHeight(80);
            remedyComment.setHeight(80);

            remedyRow.addView(remedySupplement);
            remedyRow.addView(remedyDosage);
            remedyRow.addView(remedyComment);
            remedyTable.addView(remedyRow);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < remedyTable.getChildCount(); i++) {
```

After you remove child at 0, the child at index one becomes 0, and your loop goes on to uindex one, so it just leaves it there.

Instead do this

```
while (view.getChildCount() > 0) {
  view.removeChildAt(0);
}
```